# How to build a column that automatically increases its value by 1? (HTML Table + tablesorter jQuery plugin)

Tags: jquery, html, sql, html-table, tablesorter

I want to build a left column on my tablesorter that starts with 1 and it increases its value by 1 for each row the table has. I want that column to be the first one and also, the numbers may not be sorted when I click on any header.

Comment: You can use sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [row numbering widget demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9/) - three versions of this demo can be found on the [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#widgets) under "Widgets > Other"

```
// add custom numbering widget
$.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: "numbering",
    format: function(table) {
        var c = table.config;
        $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i + 1);
        });
    }
});

$("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    // prevent first column from being sortable
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: false }
    },
    // apply custom widget
    widgets: ['numbering']
});
```